# Overwriting community controller from local

Tags: overrides, controllers, local

Let's say I wan't to override a community module named Aaa_Aaa with local module named Zzz_Zzz. It seems that no matter what I do, my local module loads after the community one, so the community module is matched first. I tried this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <aaa_aaa>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <zzz_zzz before="Aaa_aa">Zzz_Zzz</zzz_zzz>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </aaa_aaa>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

app/code/local/Zzz/Zzz/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Aaa_Aaa') . DS . 'IndexController.php';

class Zzz_Zzz_IndexController extends Aaa_Aaa_IndexController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //doesn't get to this
    }
}
```

app/etc/modules/Zzz_Zzz.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Zzz_Zzz>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Zzz_Zzz>
        <Aaa_Aaa>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Zzz_Zzz />
            </depends>
        </Aaa_Aaa>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: please clear cache & check complier is enable or not

Answer (score 2):

Change `app/etc/modules/Zzz_Zzz.xml` as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Zzz_Zzz>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Aaa_Aaa />
            </depends>
        </Zzz_Zzz>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Tried it already, doesn't work.